# Using a log transformation in an ARIMA model; how to get model predictions back on original scale?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, data-transformation

This question relates largely to the answer provided by Stephan here:

[How to know which forecasting tool to use in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354395/how-to-know-which-forecasting-tool-to-use-in-r/354397#354397)

Stephan says:

> If you work on logged data, be aware that simply taking the
>   exponential of your point forecasts will not give the expectation on
>   the original scale, for the same reason that the mean of [a lognormal
>   distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)
>   is not simply $e^\mu$, but $e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$.

I have two questions relating to this comment:

Can anyone 1) explain (roughly, not needing too much detail) why this would be the case.

And more importantly

2) How can one avoid this issue when switching back to the original scale?

For context I am trying to predict sales using an ARIMA model. I have taken a log transformation to try and make the data stationary so I can use ARIMA.

After doing this my model is giving predictions for the log of the total sales so naturally I want to raise to the power 10 to get back what my actual sales figure is predicted to be. For some reason this is not entirely the case (as pointed out by Stephan) I would like to know how to get the models predicted values back on the original scale as best as possible.

Comment: there are 2 considerations for a log transformed model ...1) the expected value of the inverse forecast incorporates the variance as "adjustment" 2) the assumption of normality of the errors leadng to presumed symmetric limits can be relaxed if you employ monte-carlo bootstrapping the residuals procedures. If outliers (pulses) are detected and incorporated into the equation they can be used to provide robust forecast limits that incorporate possible future pulses.